# Problem on deep potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

The problem is to find out the Schrödinger equation for a system of two particles $m_1$ and $m_2$ confined in a one dimensional well.

I have previously solved the problem of a single particle in a one dimensional box. But I can't get my head around to figure out the equation for two particles in 1D box. I have read how a system of two particles can be regarded as one single particle by bringing in the concept of "reduced mass". I think the equation can be written using that concept. But I can't figure out how.

Comment: Are the particles interacting in any way?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert No

Answer (score 3):

This is not a reduced mass problem, as momentum is not conserved (the potential is not translation invariant), and there is no angular momentum in 1D.

The point of the reduced mass is to *separate* the 2-particle hamiltonian into two independent equations: on for the CM-motion (constant), and one for the orbital motion.

The Hamiltonian is:

$$ H = \frac{p_1^2}{2m_1} + \frac{p_2^2}{2m_2}+V(x_1) + V(x_2)$$

Can you separate that?